# Как сделать поля для загрузки аватара профиля не обязательным?

Tags: python, django

Делаю профиль пользователя, но при попытке изменять имя, всплывает окно 'Выберите фотографию'.

models.py:

```py
class ProfileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', verbose_name='Картинка профиля')
```

html:

```html
<div class="row my-3 p-3">
  <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profilemodel.avatar.url }} " style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</div>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p style="">{{ form.username }}</p><br>
  <p>{{ profile_form.avatar }}</p>
  <button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 5px" type="submit">Save</button><br>
  <a href="{% url 'change_pass' %}" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px" class="btn btn-success">Change password</a>
</form>
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы поля для загрузки изображений было не обязательным?

Comment: функцию во `views.py` покажите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в файле с формой для этого действия добавьте для поля avatar атрибут

> required=False

Например:

```
avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
```

Подробнее тут:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#required

И в этом случае в модели профиля вам нужно указать, что поле аватар может быть пустым:

> blank=True, null=True